# How to scroll in x-axis in react-chartsjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, chart.js, bar-chart

I have implemented a bar chart in react.js and I want to figure out how I can scroll in x-axis when the values are more and more. In below chart I have some search values that user do in a day. Until now I have 100+ days and I think my problem will be bigger until we reach the end of the year when I will have more values in x-axis.

[image]

My code for the chart and the options are below.

```
  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
      },
    },
  };
```

```
  const dataForSearchBins = {
    labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Number of searches",
        data: searchBins?.map((item) => item.value),
        backgroundColor: "lightBlue",
      },
    ],
  };
```

```
<Stack>
  <Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{`Number of clicks per ${binSize.toLowerCase()}`}</Text>
  <Bar options={options} data={data} />
  <Box mb={6} />
</Stack>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [chartjs-plugin-zoom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-zoom) for this.

```
import zoomPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-zoom';
import { Chart as ChartJS} from 'chart.js';
ChartJS.register(zoomPlugin);
```

After registering zoom plugin, modify the `options` object.

```
  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
      },
      zoom: {
        pan: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'x'
        },
        zoom: {
            pinch: {
                enabled: true       // Enable pinch zooming
            },
            wheel: {
                enabled: true       // Enable wheel zooming
            },
            mode: 'x',
        }
    }
    },
  };
```

Comment: Hi Prana as i saw the package requires and the hammerjs.. I am using next.js for that project and the problem now the problem is about "Reference Error: window is not defined"

Comment: I have tried this conde snipet in my nextconfig..
  test: /hammerjs/,
  loader: "bundle-loader",
  options: {
    lazy: true
  }
but still is not a solution

Comment: ok solved with dynamic import.

Comment: @Manfre, even i tried same but i am getting same issue of "Reference Error: window is not defined" of hammer.js file. Can you share dynamic import statement by which you solved.